# Javascript not returning expected value in power apps web resource (onChange Event)

Tags: javascript, powerapps, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven, webresource

I found some [code](https://www.tamilarasu.me/2022/12/auto-populate-lookup-based-on-another-lookup-powerapps.html?sc=1682550835645#c231882370420962354) online that populates a lookup field based on another lookup field.

I have applied it to my scenario and it works fine for the first part.

In my scenario, im on an enquiry form and when i use the lookup to select the client the enquiry is related to, it auto-fills the company lookup that the client is related to. works fine.

Now for the second part, im applying the same code to look at the newly populated company field to populate the company account manager lookup but despite the code being, in theory, near identical.. im getting a console error.

Heres the first part of the code thats working fine:

```
function setCompany(executionContext) {
  // get form context
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  // get Client Company field
  var targetCompany = formContext.getAttribute("w3g_clientcompany"); //table
  //declare an empty array of object to set Client Company lookup field
  var companyName = [{}];
  // Null check on the Client Contact field
  if (formContext.getAttribute("w3g_clientcontact").getValue() !== null) {
    // get the selected Client Contact id from the lookup
    var selectedContactId = formContext.getAttribute("w3g_clientcontact").getValue()[0].id;
    // retrieve records from the Client Contacts table by filtering the id of the selected Client Contact
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("contact", "?$filter=contactid eq " + selectedContactId + "").then(
      function success(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
          var thisContact = result.entities[i];
          // Client Company lookup
          companyName[0].id = thisContact["_parentcustomerid_value"];
          companyName[0].name = thisContact["_parentcustomerid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
          companyName[0].entityType = thisContact["_parentcustomerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
          // set the value to the Client Company field
          targetCompany.setValue(companyName);
          // setCompany(executionContext);
          targetCompany.fireOnChange();  
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The above triggers onChange of the contact lookup. The below then triggers onChange of the Company Lookup and should fill the account manager lookup - but it isn't.

```
function setCAM(executionContext) {
  // get form context
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  // get CAM field
  var targetCAM = formContext.getAttribute("w3g_cam"); //table
  //declare an empty array of object to set CAM lookup field
  var CAMName = [{}];
  // Null check on the Client Company field
  if (formContext.getAttribute("w3g_clientcompany").getValue() !== null) {
    // get the selected Client Company id from the lookup
    var selectedCompanyId = formContext.getAttribute("w3g_clientcompany").getValue()[0].id;
    // retrieve records from the Client Companies table by filtering the id of the selected Client Company
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("account", "?$filter=accountid eq " + selectedCompanyId + "").then(
      function success(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
          var thisCompany = result.entities[i];
          // CAM lookup
          CAMName[0].id = thisCompany["_ownerid_value"];
          CAMName[0].name = thisCompany["_ownerid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
          CAMName[0].entityType = thisCompany["_ownerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
          // set the value to the CAM field
          targetCAM.setValue(CAMName);
          // setCAM(executionContext);
          targetCAM.fireOnChange();  
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The error in the console is as follows and I have had my mate chatGPT render it fit for human consumption:

> Uncaught (in promise) UciError: Value should be of type: entityType: Parameter Name: value[0].entityType
> at s (app.6ec6a5a348450479ff453caf37aa7414.js:33:899993)
> at p (app.6ec6a5a348450479ff453caf37aa7414.js:4:160320)
> at m (app.6ec6a5a348450479ff453caf37aa7414.js:4:160878)
> at H.setValue (10.83a0bb90e152561aa38578b389b8f645.js:4:229830)
> at success (cr214_AFCam:22:21)
> at app.6ec6a5a348450479ff453caf37aa7414.js:14:465799
> at i (app.6ec6a5a348450479ff453caf37aa7414.js:14:91380)
> at a (app.6ec6a5a348450479ff453caf37aa7414.js:14:465792)

> The error message is indicating that the value assigned to the entityType property of the CAMName object is not of the expected type.
> Looking at the code, it seems that the entityType property is being assigned the value of thisCompany["_ownerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"], which is a string representing the logical name of the entity that the lookup field references.
> However, it's possible that this value is not being set correctly in the thisCompany object, or that it is not a valid entity logical name. You may want to check the value of thisCompany["_ownerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"] in the debugger or console to see if it is a valid entity logical name.

If the value is not valid, you may need to adjust the code to retrieve the correct logical name for the entity, or update the schema to ensure that the correct logical name is being used.

I believe it might have something to do with the ownerid, which is a system field, not having a relationship with the systemuser table.. which I expected to be a system generated anyway because when you choose said owner in the lookup field, it uses the systemuser table.

But ultimately I dont have a clue, and was hoping that somebody who knows way more about this than I do, would be kind enough to help.

Answer (score 0):

One possible scenario i can think of is the owner is team for the account and you are trying to set the CAMName (user lookup) with team reference.

You could put a debugger and see what's entityType being passed to the CAMName lookup. It should be user, if not there is possible error.